# Length checking in VBA with null

Tags: vb.net, string-length

I have some code that is meant to check the length of the values in the text boxes, and if any of the boxes has no content the length of the string is 0 (or null).  Here is the code:

```
If (Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl48.Value) Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl49.Value) Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl50.Value) Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl51.Value) Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl52.Value) Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl53.Value) Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl54.Value) = 0) Then
              Do X
Else
              Do Y
End If
```

When one string is blank, the length check becomes "null" and so does the whole statement.
But if the length checks are all not null, the if statement becomes a "1" and then procedes to execute the Do X procedure again.

Any idea of what I can do?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Are you using VBA or VB.NET, please clarify!

Answer (score 3):

Your code snippet doesn't make much sense to me, but if you're using vb.net and you want "X" to execute if ANY of the values is null or 0 length then you could do the following:

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl48.Value) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty() OrElse _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl50.Value) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl51.Value) OrElse _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl52.Value) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl53.Value) OrElse _
    String.IsNullOrEmpty(Form_MainScreen.Ctl54.Value)) Then
    X()
Else
    Y()
End If
```

Using `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is a built-in function that will handle both conditions without exception. Using the `OrElse` conditional will allow slightly faster processing in that it will stop executing the conditional expressions once it receives a valid match. Using simply `Or` requires all conditional expressions to be evaluated even if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
If (Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl48.Value)=0 Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl49.Value)=0 Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl50.Value)=0 Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl51.Value)=0 Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl52.Value)=0 Or Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl53.Value)=0 Or _
    Len(Form_MainScreen.Ctl54.Value) = 0) Then
    Do X
Else
    Do Y
End If
```